# How to get docker0 bridge back?

Tags: networking, 16.04, internet, network-bridge, docker

After removing a bunch on obsolete entries from my Network settings I removed Bridge (docker0) per accident and now my containers cannot connect to the Internet.

How do I get it back? It's supposed to look like:

[image: Screenshot of network config showing docker bridge]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restarting docker service:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

was enough, as it recreates the networking bridge. Restarting my containers let them connect to the Internet again.